# HTML Editor with Macros

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, macros

We have a ASP .NET MVC CMS application where users can add/edit custom HTML content. We are using tinyMCE editor. What we want is to support some sort of a Macro mechanism where the user will add macros to the html code and user defined filters will convert the HTML.

Say for instance user will add a media item link like this:

```
[mediaUrl[id: "media_id"]]
```

or

```
${mediaUrl: {id: "media_id"}}
```

or

```
@(MediaUrl("media_id"))
```

Which is the best format? Is there a library (possibly a scripting library) to easily parse these expressions and replace them with dynamic data?

Can we use the MVC style @ expressions and dynamically translate this HTML to a partial view or should we use another library like `StringTemplate` or etc?

Note: What we have in mind is to support user-defined `HTMLFilters` so that developers can define custom expressions (like macros in wordpress) and write some filters to translate those expressions as well.

Comment: I've done similar in the past, though I took TinyMCE out of the loop for it.  I used a syntax highlighter instead because it was more for power-users who knew Razor, but you can use RazorEngine (https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine).  You might have some issues with TinyMCE 'tidying' the markup/template, particularly if you use any full-on C# in there, but worth a shot.